# How to iterate over pandas multiindex dataframe using index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df which looks like this. Date and Time are 2 multilevel index

```
                           observation1   observation2
date          Time                             
2012-11-02    9:15:00      79.373668      224
              9:16:00      130.841316     477
2012-11-03    9:15:00      45.312814      835
              9:16:00      123.776946     623
              9:17:00      153.76646      624
              9:18:00      463.276946     626
              9:19:00      663.176934     622
              9:20:00      763.77333      621
2012-11-04    9:15:00      115.449437     122
              9:16:00      123.776946     555
              9:17:00      153.76646      344
              9:18:00      463.276946     212
```

I want to run some complex process over daily data block.

Pseudo code would look like

```
 for count in df(level 0 index) :
     new_df = get only chunk for count
     complex_process(new_df)
```

So, first of all, I could not find a way to access only blocks for a date

```
2012-11-03    9:15:00      45.312814      835
              9:16:00      123.776946     623
              9:17:00      153.76646      624
              9:18:00      463.276946     626
              9:19:00      663.176934     622
              9:20:00      763.77333      621
```

and then send it for processing. I am doing this in for loop as I am not sure if there is any way to do it without mentioning exact value of level 0 column. I did some basic search and found  `df.index.get_level_values(0)`, but it returns all the values and that causes loop to run multiple times for a given day. I want to create a Dataframe per day and send it for processing.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

One easy way would be to groupby the first level of the index - iterating over the groupby object will return the group keys and a subframe containing each group.

```
In [136]: for date, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
     ...:     print(new_df)
     ...:     
                    observation1  observation2
date       Time                               
2012-11-02 9:15:00     79.373668           224
           9:16:00    130.841316           477

                    observation1  observation2
date       Time                               
2012-11-03 9:15:00     45.312814           835
           9:16:00    123.776946           623
           9:17:00    153.766460           624
           9:18:00    463.276946           626
           9:19:00    663.176934           622
           9:20:00    763.773330           621

                    observation1  observation2
date       Time                               
2012-11-04 9:15:00    115.449437           122
           9:16:00    123.776946           555
           9:17:00    153.766460           344
           9:18:00    463.276946           212
```

You can also use `droplevel` to remove the first index (the useless `date` index):

```
In [136]: for date, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
     ...:     print(new_df.droplevel(0))
     ...:
         observation1  observation2
Time
9:15:00     79.373668           224
9:16:00    130.841316           477
...
```

Comment: That helps!. I was following rather roundabout way - first finding index lable and then slicing it using iloc.

Comment: Where has this been for the last 3 years of my life. Such a clean method thank you!

Comment: This method is neat, but how to apply changes from these subframes to the main dataframe? Searching it through loc or iloc makes the computations extremely slow.

Comment: @Manaslu if you can wrap the changes into a function you can use `df.groupby('key').apply(function)`

Comment: Great! Fast and clean way to solve the problem. This is much faster than iterating over dates and getting `df.loc[date]`.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Can this multiindex dataframe be grouped by observation instead of date?

Comment: @SoumyaC You can group by "time" with `df.groupby(level=1)` (or `df.groupby(level="Time")` ... or iterate column by column with `df.items()`

Answer (score 9):

What about this?

```
for idate in df.index.get_level_values('date'):
    complex_process(df.ix[idate], idate)
```

Comment: Careful with this solution, note that each value of idate can be hit multiuple times.
You should be doing
for idate in np.unique(df.index.get_level_values('date')):
Note tha additional np.unique.

Comment: I think `df.index.get_level_values('date').unique()` may better as @melbay pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

Tagging off of @psorenson answer, we can get unique level indices and its related data frame slices without numpy as follows:

```
for date in df.index.get_level_values('date').unique():
    print(df.loc[date])
```

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, I found that the following works, too:

```py
for date in df.index.unique("date"):
    print(df.loc[date])
```

It uses the `level` optional parameter of the [`Index.unique` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html#pandas.Index.unique) introduced in version 0.23.0.

You can specify either the level number or label.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```py
for date in df.index.levels[0]:
    print(df.loc[date])
```

The difference with the `df.index.unique("date")` proposed by @sanzoghenzo is that it refers to the index level by its number rather than name.